# Connecting Django Application in One Docker Container to MySQL in Another Container

Tags: python, mysql, django, docker

Title: "Connecting Django Application in One Docker Container to MySQL in Another Container"

I have a setup with two Docker containers:

1. `mysql-container`: This container runs a MySQL image.
2. `my-django-container`: It hosts a functional Django application.

My objective is to establish a connection between the Django application running in `my-django-container` and the MySQL server in `mysql-container`. However, I'm encountering a database connection error:

```bash
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to server on '36.253.8.13' (115)")
```

Here are my Django settings for the database:

```py
"default": {
    "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
    "NAME": "name",
    "USER": "username",
    "PASSWORD": "password",
    "HOST": "172.18.0.2",  # What should I put here? The actual IP of the server `36.253.8.13` or the IP of the SQL container `172.18.0.2`?
    "PORT": "3306",  # Is this the default port for SQL?
}
```

I've also placed both containers in the same Docker network, and I can confirm that both containers are visible when I inspect the network using the `docker network inspect` command.

As a Docker novice, I would greatly appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue.

Comment: Show us your docker-compose file but generally you do set hostname and use it instead of dynamic IP https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#hostname

Comment: Sure, here's your comment formatted to be Stack Overflow valid:

---

I encountered an issue while trying to open the SQL shell within a Docker container, which makes me suspect that my initial setup may be incorrect. Here's what I tried:

```shell
root@atit:~# docker run -it mysql/mysql-server /bin/bash

[Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 8.0.32-1.2.11-server

bash-4.4# mysql -h 172.18.0.2 -u username -p

Enter password:

ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.18.0.2:3306' (110)

```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

When I tried opening the Sql shell inside the docker container itslef, I got

```
(HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.18.0.2:3306' (110)
```

Meaning my initial setup for the sql container was not configured correctly.

I removed the container and ran a new container, now I am able to connect to that SQL container.